# How can I get the residuals of correlation from tidy data

Tags: r, tidy

I have a tidy data.

```
|ID   | variable | value.x | value.y |
| --- | -------- | ------- | ------- |
|1    | Temp     | -0.71   | -0.74   |
|2    | Temp     | -0.53   | -0.50   |
|3    | Temp     | -0.48   | -0.51   |
|4    | Temp     | -0.65   | -0.66   |
|5    | Temp     | -0.49   | -0.56   |
|6    | Prep     | -0.72   | -0.75   |
|7    | Prep     | -0.64   | -0.65   |
|8    | Prep     | -0.56   | -0.54   |
|9    | Prep     | -0.46   | -0.47   |
|10   | Prep     | -0.44   | -0.44   |
```

I would like to get the residuals of correlation for each variable.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you trying to include the residuals in your plot somehow? Please clarify if so. So far it looks like you're just trying to figure out how to obtain the residuals,

Comment: Sorry for an unclear question. I just wanted to add the column of each residuals to each ID.

Comment: Ok - can you just remove the bottom of the question with the plotting code so it's clear for future visitors?

Comment: Thank you! I remove the plotting code and related text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add the residuals from a model to your data table, `modelr::add_residuals()` is a nice convenience function for this exact purpose. You can use `dplyr::group_split()` and `purrr::map()` to simultaneously run this on multiple subsets of your original data. I assumed a simple linear model but you can substitute other standard model objects.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)

d <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), variable = c("Temp", "Temp", "Temp", "Temp", "Temp", "Prep", "Prep", "Prep", "Prep", "Prep"), x = c(-0.71, -0.53, -0.48, -0.65, -0.49, -0.72, -0.64, -0.56, -0.46, -0.44), y = c(-0.74, -0.5, -0.51, -0.66, -0.56, -0.75, -0.65, -0.54, -0.47, -0.44)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

d %>% 
  group_split(variable) %>% 
  map(~add_residuals(data = .x, lm(y~x, data = .x))) %>% 
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    ID    variable     x     y    resid
#>    <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 6     Prep     -0.72 -0.75 -0.0116 
#>  2 7     Prep     -0.64 -0.65  0.00205
#>  3 8     Prep     -0.56 -0.54  0.0257 
#>  4 9     Prep     -0.46 -0.47 -0.0123 
#>  5 10    Prep     -0.44 -0.44 -0.00386
#>  6 1     Temp     -0.71 -0.74 -0.0156 
#>  7 2     Temp     -0.53 -0.5   0.0543 
#>  8 3     Temp     -0.48 -0.51 -0.00293
#>  9 4     Temp     -0.65 -0.66  0.00770
#> 10 5     Temp     -0.49 -0.56 -0.0435
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>